# Looping through days

Tags: php, date, datetime, loops

I want to return all days between a specific range.
My idea was to convert the start and end date to unix timestamp and loop through them adding 86400 (seconds of a day):

```
<?php
  $start = strtotime('2013-01-01');
  $end = strtotime('2013-02-01');

  for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i+86400)
  {
     echo date("l, d.m.y", $i) . "\n";
  }
?>
```

Unfortunately, I only get the same day:

```
Tuesday, 01.01.13
Tuesday, 01.01.13
Tuesday, 01.01.13
...
```

Comment: Wrong operator. Try `$i += 86400` instead of `$i + 86400`. And while you're at it, switch to [DateTime objects](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and explicitly add "1 day" instead of "86400 seconds".

Comment: @DCoder [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod) was created for exactly this type of task.

Comment: If you want to assign some value, you need an assignemnt operator: http://www.php.net/language.operators.assignment - and if you want to iterate something, you should take a traversable like http://php.net/dateperiod ;) - Also take care that not all days have 86400 seconds. Just saying, not that you thought so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i+86400)
```

should be

```
for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i+=86400)
```

Notice the `+=` insetad of `+` of your original code. In your code, you didnt assign new value to variable, just perform mathematical formula without result

Comment: as a note $i += 86400 is shorthand code for $i = $i + 86400

Comment: Note: this will cause issues when switching from standrd time to daylight saving times or the other way round or when leap seconds are added or such, better use salathe's approach

Comment: Same reaffirmation here - don't use the +86400 - it will screw you on the daylight savings et.

Answer (score 9):

The best practise is to use the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod) class.

```
$start = new DateTime('2013-01-01');
$end = new DateTime('2013-02-01');

foreach (new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end) as $date) {
    echo $date->format("l, d.m.y\n");
}
```

Comment: You also have `$next_day = strtotime('+1 day', $current_stamp)` if you don't want to use `DatePeriod`, but agreed that `DatePeriod` is best practice.